# how to select more options in "ManyToManyField()"?

Tags: python, django, django-models

i wanted to create a tag option for a a music model , well mainly musics accept more than one tag and there are amny kind of genres and tags ,so i wanted to make a `ManyToManyField()` that you can set more than 1 value ,also if you tag is not in add it in. to do that i thought maybe can make another `CharField()` then adding it to `tag_name` :

```
    #posts model
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    band = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    release = models.DateTimeField()
    tag_add = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
    #cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/image')
    #file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/audio')

    class Meta(self):
        ordering = ['release']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('pages:music_detail',args=[str(self.id)])

class Tags(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

but i stuck here too ,i really dont know how to add a models field data to another models field ?
i would appreciate if you guide me here

Comment: Your code seems okay, what exactly is the problem or error message?

Comment: problem is that i couldnt reach my purpose ,i mean idk how to add ```tag_add``` to ```tag_name``` data ,and how to let user select more than one option in ```tags```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a user to select more than one tag, they simply have to `ctrl` then click on the tags. For Android I suppose it's long-pressing.
For adding a tag if it's not in the models, you don't need a field for that. In the admin, you can just click on the `+` sign.

Comment: ive read about ```ctr``` but in there are a few sites(in my list) that let you select tags or genres just by clicking on them ,i mean its more user friendly ,forexample this site let you choose tags just by clicking

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. You can use JS such that the selected items are added to a list. Then the list can be appended into the tags model. Incase there is a new one, it just gets added to that list and appended to the model as well.

Comment: so its not possible in django.srry i ask again but how about my 2nd problem, adding amodel field to another models field data, like a user create new tag just by typing it

Comment: With Django only, you have to submit the tag to the model by using a button. With Django + JS, you can add it by just typing and using JS to call the Django view responsible for saving the tag.

Comment: sorry if i ask awhile later but is it possible to disable multiple select with ```ctrl```? allowing to select only 1 option?

Comment: Do you mean unselecting the selected choices or specifically limiting the choices to only one?

Comment: limiting it to only 1 choice

Comment: Then I suggest you ditch `ManyToMany` for `ForeignKey`

Comment: foreign key only accept one value ?

Comment: Yes. Try it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250770/discussion-between-nicolas-darksoul-and-sajeyks-mwangi).